# "Directory is not under storage root path magento 2

Tags: magento2, directory

```
module.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Greenplank_UploaderFix">
    </module>
</config>

registration.php

<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Greenplank_UploaderFix',
    __DIR__
);

di.xml

<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryResolver"
                type="Greenplank\UploaderFix\App\Filesystem\DirectoryResolver"/>
</config>

DirectoryResolver.php

<?php
namespace Greenplank\UploaderFix\App\Filesystem;
 
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
 
/**
 * Magento directories resolver.
 */
class DirectoryResolver
{
    /**
     * @var DirectoryList
     */
    private $directoryList;
 
    /**
     * @param DirectoryList $directoryList
     */
    public function __construct(DirectoryList $directoryList)
    {
        $this->directoryList = $directoryList;
    }
 
    /**
     * Validate path.
     *
     * Gets real path for directory provided in parameters and compares it with specified root directory.
     * Will return TRUE if real path of provided value contains root directory path and FALSE if not.
     * Throws the \Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException in case when directory path is absent
     * in Directories configuration.
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @param string $directoryConfig
     * @return bool
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException
     */
    public function validatePath($path, $directoryConfig = DirectoryList::MEDIA)
    {
        $realPath = realpath($path);
        $root = realpath($this->directoryList->getPath($directoryConfig));
 
        return strpos($realPath, $root) === 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail on what the issue is?

Comment: When i upload the any images through gallery from admin panel i got error but i try my solution it is not working for me can you help me.  Thanks